# Testar integridade de dados utilizando MySQL Transactions

Tags: mysql, integridade

Estou utilizando um sistema ecommerce no qual utiliza [MySQL Transactions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html) para manter integridade dos dados, por exemplo na compra simultânea de vários clientes de um mesmo produto aonde o sistema precisa diminuir do estoque e prevenir que o mesmo não fique negativo.

Tecnicamente, como o MySQL faz o controle para evitar que uma requisição/consulta de um usuário dê conflito com a de outro(s) usuário(s) e assim mantendo essa integridade?

Qual a melhor prática para testar essa integridade? Talvez usar algum cliente HTTP para gerar várias requisições HTTP no qual simularia compras?

Existe um número de consultas simultâneas onde o uso de Transactions acaba sendo desnecessário? Se sim, a partir de quantas usuários simultâneos temos que nos preocupar com a integridade utilizando MySQL Transactions?

Answer (score 0):

Antes de responder sua pergunta, note que para garantir a atomicidade de suas operações no banco de dados, você deve se preocupar com o [Isolation Level](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/set-transaction.html), ou seja, garantir que durante sua compra os selects executados e subsequentes commits sejam executados atomicamente, ou seja, sem concorrência. Perceba que sem isso, mesmo com transações você ainda pode ter problemas de concorrência.

Uma outra maneira de resolver seu problema é fazer com que o código que executa tais operações seja `synchronized`, ou seja, apenas uma *Thread* é executada por vez para operações de compra.

Agora, respondendo sua pergunta, você pode criar testes unitários que executem a mesma operação de compra em *Threads* separadas. Outra maneira, é utilizar o [JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) ou [gatling](http://gatling.io/#/) para executar esses testes.